# SetTheme does not work when using viewBinding

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-viewbinding, android-attributes

I have two themes in my app (dark and light mode) and I could change the themes without any problem.
But, since I used the viewBinding, the setTheme() function did not work and I can't change the activity's theme anymore.
Does anyone know what's the problem?

This is my old code (which worked)

```
setTheme(getAppTheme());
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
```

And the new code (which does not work)

```
setTheme(getAppTheme());
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

Thank you for taking the time to read, and sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: How are you initializing your binding variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be initializing your binding variable before you're setting your theme. You have to initialize your activity binding after you've set the theme, for it to work correctly.

```
setTheme(getAppTheme());
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```